# ArcGIS Route (Change direction phrase structure)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing

Is it possible to change direction text phrasing? at the moment on the route directions, it mostly starts with Turn(right/left) depending on the esriDMT maneuverType. But some people prefer to see an instruction started with "continue then turn (right/left)" rather than "turn(right/left) then continue"?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of directions is not exposed via the UI of ArcGIS Desktop, however you can modify the directions style to meet your requirements.

You would need to edit one .xml file, `resources.xml` stored at `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\NetworkAnalyst\Directions` folder. This is undocumented, so you would need to try multiple times changing strings and substrings of tags related to turns before you will get the result you need.

As always, do a backup of the source `resources.xml` before making any changes. It's also helpful to start with baby steps and just try to make a tiny change at one place to verify that this change is being reflected in ArcMap when generating directions (for instance, instead of `{Start}`, you could have `{StartTESTCHANGED}`). Keep in mind, that the same strings/substrings may be used in multiple places, so the directions may look right in one place and odd at another. You might need to re-order tags then to construct a proper English sentence.

I've done a similar work tailoring the directions style to a customer needs and remember going through a lot of pain trying to make changes appear consistent throughout the whole directions. You might try it out and see whether it is worth the effort; I think standard directions style is good enough.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will try test around the effects of the changes. The reason behind why I opened up this question is because when I compare waze instructions to arcgis intructions, waze gives a friendly direction by having "[how many meters] then right/left UI". arcgis seems to get the turn sign on the start of the routeline. If only has options to make the turn on the end.

Comment: I do understand you. Please do some testing and see whether this can be tweaked to your needs.